# .Net: Collection for storing numeric ranges returning matching ranges for a given value

Tags: .net, collections

I am i search of an effective implementation of a collection for these requirements:

- can store numeric range objects (from/to)
- can return all ranges of the collection that contain a certain value

Example:
Assume that the collection contains these range objects:
Item 1: 5 to 10
Item 2: 7 to 9
Item 3: 3 to 6

Then, taking '8' as the argument, the collection shall return items 1 and 2
The ranges can overlap. The returned range objects need not to be in any specific order.
Start and end values are only limited by the value range of the UInt32 type (as opposed to the simple example above).

Is it possible to implement this using one of the popular collection libraries, like C5?

The implementation shall be efficient, implementations that require to iterate through lots of collections elements are trivial, and that's what I already have.

Comment: are the ranges fix/dynamic? is there any maximum/minimum value?

Comment: Well can't you create a `Range` object with the from/to values and a convenience `Contains` method, and then just have a `List<Range>`, using LINQ: `var filtered = ranges.Where(r => r.Contains(x))`? That's only O(N) in the number of ranges (not their size).

Comment: @yossico: The ranges are fixed and do not change during the lifetime of the collection. The range start and end can be in the full range of the UInt32 type.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: OK, but something like O(log N) would be nicer...
There can be several hundreds of such ranges

Comment: "Severqal hundreds" doesn't make it worth making a complicated solution IMO - you can check thousands of ranges in the blink of an eye do you have firm performance requirements that a simple solution *don't* meet? How often do you need to perform this filtering?

Comment: If you need performance then use an a database.

Comment: Well, performance is to such a big deal in my case, but I hoped someone had a simple, straightforward solution that I simply didn't find myself. Anyhow, thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 1):

You can solve it in different ways, One nice way.

If the list of ranges is not too big. You can focus on building a `List<List<T>>` or `List<T>[]` while using the range id i.e 8 as a Index or a Key for returning the Items that containing this index.

- For dynamic size i would use `List<List<T>>` where T stands for the object type of Item.
- For fix size Array will be the better choice.

Array

Index - Values

```
0 -
1 - 
2 - 
3 - Item 3
4 - Item 3
5 - Item 1, Item 3
6 - Item 1, Item 3
7 - Item 1, Item 2
8 - Item 1, Item 2
9 - Item 1, Item 2
10 - Item 1
```

In this method you can access the items that contain the requested range by **O(1)** by doing `myArray[index]` will return the List of Items.

Complexity:

- **Building** will be **O(Count(Items) * Max(Item.Length))**
- **Retrieving** will be **O(1)**

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a data structure called an **Interval Tree**. There are a couple of implementations for .NET like this one:

https://github.com/mbuchetics/RangeTree

or this one

https://github.com/vvondra/Interval-Tree